# Laravel 8, User = null, but session still has "_token", session persistence problem?

Tags: php, laravel, http, session, laravel-8

## The Problem:

After successful initial "csrf-cookie" and "login" requests, the authenticated user seems to disappear from the session on all subsequent requests.

`$request->user()` and `Auth::user()` and `auth()-user()` all return **null**.

`$request->session()->all()` returns just a "_token" field, and `$request->session()->has('users')` and `$request->session()->has('user')` both return **false**.

## Context:

*This only occurs on my production server (I've tried both a Laravel Forge server and my own server with setting up Nginx manually).*

This is a SPA backend, using Laravel 8. Using Laravel's built in Sanctum authentication. Using database session driver (although I've tried all the others, the driver does not seem to be the issue, and I can see the sessions in my database).

My session config currently (although I have tried other configs to no avail):

```
same_site = 'none'
domain = null
secure = true
http_only = true
```

### What I've Tried:

Countless google searches, have not found any issues or solutions that seem to apply to my situation.

I have tried digging into the session and request objects immediately before and after the problem occurs (as described in the problem section) and have not gotten any useful information that way.

I have tried playing around with the session config... changing the "same-site", "secure", etc. variables.

Comment: Sanctum SPA auth is cookie-based. Are you losing the cookie somehow? Do your SPA & API domains share the same TLD?

Comment: I don't think I'm losing the cookie, as the request headers all contain the cookies set by the csrf-cookie request. My SPA and API also DO share the same TLD.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, turned out to be extremely simple/silly: I had to add the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` middleware to my route (specifically for me, in this case it was to the 'api' middleware group).